# How to write $n!=a^{\alpha_0}(a+1)^{\alpha_1}(a+2)^{\alpha_2}\cdots(a+r)^{\alpha_r}$?

Tags: number-theory, factorial

We know that $n!=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots3\cdot2\cdot1, n\in \mathbb N$. Now I am willing to write $n!$ as $a^{\alpha_0}(a+1)^{\alpha_1}(a+2)^{\alpha_2}\cdots(a+r)^{\alpha_r}$ where $a, r, \alpha\in \mathbb N$.

My question is: how to find such $a$ and $\alpha$? For the second one, I think de Polignac's formula can be use but not sure about it. Can some one help me how to solve this one ? Should I include more criteria on the problems ?

Please help me.

Comment: Is $0\in\mathbb{N}$? If yes, do you allow $\alpha=0$?  
For example, how would you present $15$ in this form? $15=3^1\cdot4^0\cdot5^1$?

Comment: (1) I have excluded "$0\in \mathbb N$". (2) And each $\alpha$ must be natural number. (3) I wish to express $15!$ not 15 .

Comment: Search for the text "Euler also developed a convergent product approximation for the non-integer factorials"  in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial - The formula presented there may be somewhat close to what you want.

Comment: @Anjan3: Then you should change "Now I am willing to write $n$ as..." to "$n!$ as..."

Comment: I apologise. It was a mistake indeed. Sorry for that. Correcting

Comment: Its done now. Please let me know if there is any more mistake